# EnumProperty UI 'Dropdown List' Not Displaying in UI element

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties

So I am writing a little add-on for myself (whilst learning UI dev for Blender) and I am attempting to add a DropDown element via an Enum using EnumProperty.

However, after a successful compiling it still does not display in the UI element.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Scene
from bpy.props import PointerProperty, EnumProperty

# UI Section

class axono_panel:
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Axono"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}


class axono_main_panel(axono_panel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "axono_main_panel"
    bl_label = "Axono Rasterisation Settings"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout    
        scn = bpy.context.scene
        
        layout.prop(scn, "prop", text='Object')
        layout.label(text="Export Settings")
        

class axono_second_panel(axono_panel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "axono_main_panel"
    bl_label = "Camera Settings"
    
    projection_items = [
        ("isometric", "Isometric", 0),
        ("dimetric", "Dimetric", 1),
        ("trimetric", "Trimetrix", 2),
    ]

    camera_projection_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(    
        items=projection_items,
        name="Camera Projection Types",
#        default="isometric",
#        description="Select a typical Axonometric Camera Perspective",
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Axonometric Position")
        
        cp = context.scene
        
        col = layout.column()
        layout.prop(cp, "camera_projection_enum", text="Projections")
        
        
class axono_third_panel(axono_panel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "axono_main_panel"
    bl_label = "Resolution Settings"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Render Resolution")
        
class axono_footer_panel(axono_panel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "axono_footer_panel"
    bl_label = "Axono Rasterisation Render"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout    
        scn = bpy.context.scene               

    
# Registration Section

classes = (
    axono_main_panel, 
    axono_second_panel, 
    axono_third_panel, 
    axono_footer_panel, 
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    Scene.prop = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.prop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: You can't serialize data in interface elements like panels or menus, so you have to store it on an object that can serialize it (Property group or an ID type for instance)

Comment: That's what I assumed originally. But was receiving 'Could not Register - Error'. Switched it up and the script compiled correctly. Shouldn't have really assumed that would be the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `PropertyGroup` class and register it to the `bpy.types.Scene`

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import *


class Axono:
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Axono'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}


class AXONO_PT_main_panel(Panel, Axono):
    bl_label = 'Axono Rasterisation Settings'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        prop = context.scene.custom_prop

        layout.prop(prop, 'object', text='Object')
        layout.label(text='Export Settings')


class AXONO_PT_second_panel(Panel, Axono):
    bl_label = 'Camera Settings'
    bl_parent_id = 'AXONO_PT_main_panel'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        prop = context.scene.custom_prop

        layout.label(text='Axonometric Position')

        col = layout.column()
        layout.prop(prop, 'camera_projection', text='Projections')


class AXONO_PT_third_panel(Panel, Axono):
    bl_label = 'Resolution Settings'
    bl_parent_id = 'AXONO_PT_main_panel'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        layout.label(text='Render Resolution')


class AXONO_PT_footer_panel(Panel, Axono):
    bl_idname = 'axono_footer_panel'
    bl_label = 'Axono Rasterisation Render'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        prop = context.scene.custom_prop


class AXONO_PG_custom_properties(PropertyGroup):

    object : PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)

    camera_projection : EnumProperty(
        name = 'Camera Projection Types',
        description = 'Select a typical Axonometric Camera Perspective',
        items = (
            ('ISOMETRIC', 'Isometric', ''),
            ('DIMETRIC', 'Dimetric', ''),
            ('TRIMETRIC', 'Trimetrix', ''),
        ),
       default = 'ISOMETRIC',
    )


classes = (
    AXONO_PT_main_panel,
    AXONO_PT_second_panel,
    AXONO_PT_third_panel,
    AXONO_PT_footer_panel,
    AXONO_PG_custom_properties,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.custom_prop = PointerProperty(type=AXONO_PG_custom_properties)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.custom_prop


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```